# Disable vibrate feedback ontouch in Tizen Web App on Samsung Watch

Tags: android, tizen, tizen-web-app, vibration, onpress

I'm making a game for Samsung **watches** using Tizen Web App and HTML5 Canvas. I'm trying to disable vibrate feedback every time the user presses the screen.

I've tried `return false` at the end of the event, and that didn't work.

The only other idea I've found is adding `tizen.feedback.stop()` at the beginning of the event, however this only forces the watch to stop vibrating after it's already started, making it unpredictable. However, this makes it seems like the vibration starts *before* the event, but I know it's possible cause I've seen other apps without the vibrate feedback.

And all it takes is an element to click on for it to vibrate:

```
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; background-color:red;" onmousedown="click();"></div>
```

So how do I disable vibrate on touch **for good**? Thanks.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, you wish to disable vibration when a user touches the screen. Am I right? If so, did you try using `navigator.vibrate(0);`? Please refer to https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/guides/w3c/device/vibration/

Comment: @JohnDoyle Ya, I tried that, but it does the same as `tizen.feedback.stop()`, where it stops the vibrate _after_ it starts.

Comment: You didn't do anything and vibration happens. That's odd. can you provide me a sample code? I also have a Tizen based watch.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite a solution, but a work-around that worked for me:

Instead of using `onclick` or `onmousedown`, I used `onmousemove` because it doesn't vibrate and it only gets called on touch because it's a touchscreen. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯